# Forecasting with ets: Is my model performing well?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, exponential-smoothing

I'm new to forecasting and playing around with some forecasting techniques. I used the `ets` function from the `forecast` package to automatically select the model. I want to do a check to see if the model has adequately captured the information in the data.

I used the `checkresiduals()` function and the Ljung-Box test with `Box.test()` as described [here](https://otexts.com/fpp2/residuals.html).

`checkresiduals` gives me a p-value lower than 0.05 where the Ljung-Box test gives me a p-value greater than 0.05.

I was suspecting a p-value greater than 0.05 by both methods. I'm really confused now.

**Question**

Is my model correct? Or is it incorrect? And can it be optimized with for example ARIMA?

**Data**

```
    month_year  n
1   2017-12-01  75
2   2018-01-01  253
3   2018-02-01  99
4   2018-03-01  155
5   2018-04-01  186
6   2018-05-01  290
7   2018-06-01  400
8   2018-07-01  248
9   2018-08-01  148
10  2018-09-01  167
11  2018-10-01  181
12  2018-11-01  136
13  2018-12-01  94
14  2019-01-01  135
15  2019-02-01  134
16  2019-03-01  168
17  2019-04-01  172
18  2019-05-01  206
19  2019-06-01  896
20  2019-07-01  270
21  2019-08-01  183
22  2019-09-01  174
23  2019-10-01  164
24  2019-11-01  100
25  2019-12-01  123
26  2020-01-01  182
27  2020-02-01  155
28  2020-03-01  178
```

**Code**

```
# define time serie #
timeserie.ts <- ts(data$n, start=c(2017, 12), end=c(2020, 03), freq=12)
time <- time(timeserie.ts)

# split data in train & test #
n.valid <- 2
n.train <- length(tijdserie.ts) - n.valid
train.ts <- window(tijdserie.ts, start=time[1], end=time[n.train])
valid.ts <- window(tijdserie.ts, start=time[n.train+1], end=time[n.train+n.valid])

# use ETS to find the 'best' model #
modelfit <- ets(train.ts, model = "ZZZ")

# write away residuals #
res <- residuals(modelfit)

# ACF plot #
acf(res)
```

[image: acf plot]

```
#checkresiduals test#
checkresiduals(modelfit)

data:  Residuals from ETS(M,N,M)
Q* = 19.517, df = 3, p-value = 0.0002137
```

[image: Residuals plot]

```
# Ljung-Box test #
Box.test(res, type = "Ljung-Box")

data:  res
X-squared = 3.1101, df = 1, p-value = 0.07781
```

```
# forecast 6 months #
plot(forecast(modelfit, 6))
```

[image]

Comment: The result of `Box.test` and `checkresiduals` are different because, although they are both Ljung-Box tests, when you don't set the lag (or `fitdf`), they have different defaults. Here you can compare the result of `checkresiduals` to `Box.test(res, lag = 17,type = "Ljung-Box",fitdf = 14)`, they will be the same. Aside from that, whether your model is "correct" depends mostly on whatever out-of-data knowledge you have about the spike in 2019: is it likely to re-occur in 2020, as your ETS model believes, or is it an anomaly, as @IrishStat suggests?

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach has a ton of assumptions. First of all there are no anomalous data points . A more cautioned approach is to identify the anomalies:

[image]

The presumptive approach that you are using BELIEVES the data rather than challenging it.  The acf of the residuals issue that are encountering is due to model mis-specification and avoidance of identifying latent deterministic structure.

Consider the following model with reasonable sufficiency statistics here

[image]

The model form with no arima needed is here

[image]

with residual plot here

[image]

The Actual/Fit/Forecast graph is here with a better looking forecast ..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to consider what 'performing well' means. You could define this is how well the model predicts actual data. For that using a hold out sample and something like a MAPE (there are many alternatives, this is the one I prefer) is very useful. The problem is that you can predict the hold out sample well and not predict after that well (but there is no solution I know to that).